# AngularJS and $http.get request doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I have a strange issue and i don't know what causes it.

I made an html page which consists in a form. When you fill it and press the button "Submit", AngularJS performs a query to an online db for getting certain values, according to what you have written in the form (it's a search for locations near the location specified in the form).

That's query is made by a HTTP GET request, which returns the values you are looking for.

It's a part of a more complex system developed using Google App Engine.

When I upload the html page on the server, and I access it through browser (typing the URL of the page) it works correctly.

But when I double click on the same html page, stored in a folder on my PC, and I open it in the browser, and try to perform the same actions it doesn't work.

I thought it was caused by non-absolute URL and dependencies, but URL are absolute and there aren't dependecies (or I didn't find them).

Could you tell me what's wrong? I want to access it double-clicking and make it work because, in that way, developing will become faster than writing, uploading and testing everytime.

That's the html code of the page

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="demoApp">

<head>
    <title>Search a location</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/helloworld.css">
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="HttpGetController"> 
    <br>Insert your data<br/>
<br>Name: <input type="text" name="Name" ng-model="Name"><br/>
<br>Category: <input type="text" name="Cat" ng-model="Cat"><br/>
<br>Latitude: <input type="number" step=any name="Lat" ng-model="Lat"/><br/>
<br>Longitude: <input type="number" step=any name="Lon" ng-model="Lon"/><br/>
<br>Distance:<br/>
<input type="radio" name="Ray" value="10" ng-model="Ray"> 10<br>
<input type="radio" name="Ray" value="20" ng-model="Ray"> 20<br>
<input type="radio" name="Ray" value="30" ng-model="Ray"> 30<br>
<input type="radio" name="Ray" value="40" ng-model="Ray"> 40<br>
<input type="radio" name="Ray" value="50" ng-model="Ray"> 50<br>
<button ng-click="SendData()">Submit</button>

<h3>Dati Page: {{ PostDataResponse }}</h3>
<h3>Dati Page2: {{ ResponseDetails }}</h3>
<p ng-bind-html="htmlAdText"></p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">
</script>  

<script>
var demoApp = angular.module("demoApp", []);



demoApp.controller("HttpGetController", function ($scope, $http, $sce) {
$scope.PostDataResponse = "null";
$scope.ResponseDetails="null";

$scope.SendData = function () {
        var URL = "https://xxxxxxxxx.appspot.com/xxxxxx?"+"Name="+$scope.Name+"&Cat="+$scope.Cat+"&Lat="+$scope.Lat+"&Lon="+$scope.Lon+"&Ray="+$scope.Ray;
        $scope.ResponseDetails=URL;
        $http.get(URL).success(function(data) {
              $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
              $scope.htmlAdText = $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
          });

       };

});


</script>        

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't run AJAX requests for resources on a different server due to the same-origin policy, unless the server specifically allows this (by setting a header in the reply). Double-clicking the html on your computer will open the page in the `file:///` environment, and AJAX will cease to work.

Comment: I got it. Thanks